# Text file updated only device is connected with xcode only

Tags: ios

I created a text file in ios and it is stored in Data files in following location.`Sandbox => Documents => mylogfile.txt.`

This file is updates only when I connected my Device with Mac and Xcode only.If I eject the device, and connect again to see the updated text file. It is not updated. It will be same as old file. The log file does not updated when disconnected from PC.
How to update text file on all time.

**My Code:**

```
-(void)logme:(NSString *)mymessage
{
    NSString *content = mymessage;

    //Get the file path
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"locationlog.txt"];

    //create file if it doesn't exist
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileName contents:nil attributes:nil];

    //append text to file (you'll probably want to add a newline every write)
    NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:fileName];
    [file seekToEndOfFile];
    [file writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [file closeFile];
}
```

and called this log file like,

```
[self logme:myHTML];
```

Comment: Please post your code for creating/updating the text file so that we can find the problem and maybe a solution :) .

Comment: This log file is updated for every 1 minute.

Comment: Did you tried to add `[file synchronizeFile];` before the `[file closeFile];` ?

Comment: no it is also not works

Comment: basically My application run in background and fetch data from server periodically. I want to see the fetched data even i am not connected to PC. then only i can check how much battery it consumes. If it connected with PC,it is always charing.So I am not able test battery consumption for this task